# Как работат select()?

Tags: c++, c

Я бы хотел узнать, что в нем происходит. Видел исходники, но разобраться в них мне крайне сложно.
Просто суть хочу узнать. Есть набор файловых дескрипторов, пусть мы их все проверяем на готовность к чтению. У select есть бесконечный цикл, там, он, по всей видимости, пробегается по всем дескрипторам и... И что дальше? какую информацию в себе хранит файловый дескриптор, что ему говорит, что файл готов к чтению?

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/select.c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> У select есть бесконечный цикл

В ядре ОС нет никакого цикла. Иначе бы Ваш вызов *select* подвесил всю систему. Всё построено на прерываниях.

> какую информацию в себе хранит файловый дескриптор

Это совершенно не важно. Тем боле, что в разных ОС - разную. Просто с точки зрения ОС, ваш сокет - это почти обычный файл. А все файлы описываются соответствующими дескрипторами и имеют свой номер в таблице дескрипторов.

Вызывая *select()* Вы просто говорите ОС, что вы ожидаете прихода прерывания от любого из перечисленных в наборе сокетов (файлов).

> что ему говорит, что файл готов к чтению?

Предположим, что Вы пытаетесь отправить на печать строку текста. А принтер не готов. Что произойдёт? Функция вывода (например - *printf()*) повиснет на ожидании готовности. Вы нажимаете на принтере кнопочку "Вкл", принтер начинавет работать и посылает **прерывание** ОС. Ядро ОС забирает буфер из *printf()* и отправляет его на устройство.

Аналогично происходит и с сокетами. Передавая *select()* наборы сокетов, Вы говорите ОС, что Вас интересует возможность прочитать или записать данные в сокеты, которые заданы их парами IP/Port. Когда драйвер сетевой карточки получает пакет данных с соответствующей парой IP/Port он посылает прерывание сетевой подсистеме ядра ОС. Та снимает с ожидания Вашу программу и сообщает ей, какой конкретно сокет готов к передаче данных. Вы их забираете, обрабатывает и опять повисаете на *srlrct()*...

Comment: *`"В ядре ОС нет никакого цикла."`* -- цикл там, конечно же, есть, а не подвисает все из-за того, что для ожидания мы (изнутри цикла) вызываем планировщик, который уже решает, кому передать управление. Может вернуться к нам (когда-нибудь это обязательно произойдет), а может в любой готовый исполняться процесс

Comment: @avp - "цикл там, конечно же, есть"
- Я даже спорить с этим не буду :-) Смотрите раздел 5.1.1 (стр 391) книги Таненбаум Э., Бос Х. "Современные операционные системы". 4-е изд. Я надеюсь, с Таненбаумом Вы спорить не станете ?

Comment: @avp Так, стоп. Все это конечно круто. В UNIX что хранит в себе файловый дескриптор? Цикл в самом select, разве нет? Разве в select не осуществляется пробежка по всем дескрипторам? Не очень понял, почему вы про ядро заговорили. С принтером не понял, а почему? Почему так произойдет и наш printf будет чего-то ожидать. Почему бы не пойти дальше и не забыть про printf?

Comment: @avp в сорсах  select-а невооруженным глазом виден бесконечный цикл

Comment: @АндрейПетров - "Разве в select не осуществляется пробежка по всем дескрипторам? "
- Нет. Список файловых дескрипторов в *select()* - это просто битовая маска. В ней "1" означает, что данный файл Вас интересует, "0" - не интересует. И никто не там никак не "бегает". Приходит **прерывание** от драйвера сетевой карточки типа "Rx buffer is full". По прерыванию управление передаётся сетевой подсистеме ядра. Она сопостовляет IP:Port из принятого адреса назначенния в пакете со списком открытых сокетов (в каждом сокете содержится IP и Port) и находит сокет, которому соответствует пакет.

Comment: Если такого сокета нет - пакет отбрасывается - он чужой. Далее по списку сокетов определяется, какому процессу принадлежит этот сокет. И только после этого, ОС проверяет - а находится ли этот сокет в списке ожидающих? Если нет - пакет отбрасывается. И только **после** всего этого, операционка передаёт управление данному процессу, на оператор, челующий за *select()*...

Comment: @Sergey
В принципе понятно куда копать, тогда что же значит ожидание для программы? 
Вот программа сидит в select и ждет, ждать - это что за действие для программ такое ?

Comment: @Sergey, я не собираюсь спорить ни с Танненбаумом, ни с вами. Я говорил о цикле в функции ядра `do_select()`

Comment: @АндрейПетров, *`"в сорсах select-а невооруженным глазом виден бесконечный цикл"`* -- а если посмотреть пристальней, то из него есть `break;` / *`"Не очень понял, почему вы про ядро заговорили.`"* -- т.к. `select()` (тот код, ссылку на который вы привели) это часть ядра

Comment: @АндрейПетров - "ждать - это что за действие для программ такое ?"  Реализация "ожидания" возлагается не на прикладную программу, а на ядро ОС.  Там, в ядре, есть несколько списков процессов, которые должны выполняться. Не вдаваясь в подробности, можно сказать, что таских списков всего два: готовых к выполнению (1)  и  чего-то ожидающих (2). Ядро пробегает по первому списку и каждому из процессов в этом списке выделяет по кванту процессорного времени, заданному в параметрах ядра. Допустим - по 10 мс.

Comment: @АндрейПетров Процессы из второго списка (ожидания) никак в этом не участвуют. Вызвав *select()* Вы командуете ОС переместить ваш процесс в список ожидания и одновремнно информируете ОС о том, что именно он ждёт - список сокетов.

Получив прерывание, ОС приостанавливает текущий процесс и просматривает список **ожидаемых** событий. Если такое прерывание есть, то выясняется, какой именно процесс ждёт это прерывание.  Если такой процесс найден, то он переносится из очереди ожидания в очередь готовых к выполнению. ОС  анализирует приоритеты процессов в очереди и запускает самый приоритетный.

Answer (score 4):

Вызывая select, Вы говорите операционной системе - вот эти сокеты мне интересны, на этих факт чтения, на этих - запись. Операционная система сама решает, когда произошло запрашиваемое событие и отдает результат. То есть, с точки зрения приложение, это блокирующий запрос, с точки зрения операционной системы - это просто запрос, который поставили в очередь.

То есть, как именно внутри реализован select - это детали конкретной операционной системы (скажу больше в windows и linux они только визуально похожи, а внутри совершенно по разному устроены).

В приведенных сорцах просто заполняют другую структуру, более удобную ядру и отдают ему. Если я не ошибаюсь, то похоже там используют другую функцию с такой же функциональностью - poll.

Что же такое "файловый дескриптор"? считайте это просто неким номерком, по которому операционная система внутри себя сопоставляет с реальным объектом.

Comment: `В приведенных сорцах просто заполняют другую структуру, более удобную ядру и отдают ему. Если я не ошибаюсь, то похоже там используют другую функцию с такой же функциональностью - poll. ` — на самом деле нет: у `poll()` и `select()` разные реализации вплоть до постановки в очереди ожидания (`do_poll()` и `do_select()` соответственно — всё самое интересное там)...

Comment: я до последнего сомневался, но имя poll в функции do_select чуть заинтриговало

Answer (score 1):

Если разобрать фунцию `do_select()`, то можно выяснить следующее.

В структуре связанной с [файловым дескриптором](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/file.h#L36) (продолжение [тут](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/fs.h#L915) и [тут](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/fs.h#L1820)) есть указатель на специфичную для каждого типа файловых дестрипторов (сокет, терминал, plain file и т.д.) [функцию poll](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/poll.h#L86), которая вызывается  вот тут    `mask = vfs_poll(f.file, wait);` в "бесконечном цикле" в `do_select()`.

Именно она определяет, есть ли готовые для чтения данные или готов ли дескриптор в данный момент для записи данных или есть ли в данный момент прочие события, связанные с дескриптором.

Если такие (заданные в передаваемой в select маске) дескрипторы обнаружены, то мы возвращаемся (также возвращаемся при получении сигнала и истечении таймаута). Если готовых дескрипторов нет, то ожидаем, передавая управление в scheduler, тем самым возобновляя какой-то из других процессов OS, готовых к исполнению.

Comment: Добавлю, что помимо проверки на готовность основное, что делает «метод» `.poll`, вызываемый из `vfs_poll()`, — это ставит процесс в очередь ожидания, связанную с данным файлом.